# Exact Match Elasticsearch with Standard Tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a field with standard tokenizer, and the documents inserted like below :

1

```
{
  name : Hello World
}
```

2

```
{
  name : Hello World Welcome
}
```

3

```
{
  name : Hello World Welcome to the World
}
```

How to query "Hello World" and return all the documents with term Hello and World and the first document with the exact match "Hello World" will have a higher score than others

Answer (score 0):

You can very simply achieve it like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Hello World"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "Hello World"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The first `match` constraint will match all three documents and the `should/match_phrase` constraint will give a boost to the first document, i.e. it'll get a slightly higher score than the other two documents.